# Why does module.exports still work when called before defining exported properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code:

```
var config = module.exports = {};

config.foo = {...};
```

This works find, but I'd like to understand why.

I feel like I can wrap my head around the implementation below because it appears to make more sense to export config, not set config equal to module.exports.

```
var config = {};
config.foo = {...};

module.exports = config;
```

Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var config = module.exports = {};
```

is equivalent to

```
var config = (module.exports = {});
```

and

```
module.exports = {};
var config = module.exports;
```

The value getting exported here is `{}`. Because `config` and `module.exports` are just references to the same object `{}`, the property `foo` can still get added to that object via either variable `module.exports` or `config`.